# Issue with GTK and D

Tags: macos, gtk, d, dmd

OK, so I'm trying to experiment a bit with D and Gtk.

On OSX, I download the sources and did the typical `make`, `sudo make install`.

**Now the Gtk sources are installed here :**

```
/usr/local/include/d/gktd-2
```

However, when I'm trying to build one of the demos included (e.g. `/demos/gtk/HelloWorld.d`), with :

```
dmd -I/usr/local/include/d/gktd-2 HelloWorld.d
```

**The compiler still complains :**

```
HelloWorld.d(24): Error: module MainWindow is in file 'gtk/MainWindow.d' which cannot be read
import path[0] = /usr/local/include/d/gktd-2
import path[1] = /usr/share/dmd/src/phobos
import path[2] = /usr/share/dmd/src/druntime/import
```

What am I missing?

---

**UPDATE :**

I *think* I got it to work, but it's one of those cases where I simply don't know *how* that happened... lol

Comment: is there a `gtk` directory in `/usr/local/include/d/gktd-2`?

Comment: @ratchetfreak Yep, there is. (with `MainWindow.d` in it)

Comment: Are you sure the folder is `/usr/local/include/d/gktd-2` and not `/usr/local/include/d/gtkd-2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it seems like a typo - /usr/local/include/d/**gktd-2** seems incorrect. It should be something like /usr/local/include/d/**gtkd-2** . Following should work: `dmd -I/usr/local/include/d/gtkd-2 HelloWorld.d` (note the change from "gktd" to "gtkd").